# Indirect Register Addressing

Tags: unix, assembly, nasm, addressing-mode

I am trying to figure out how register indirect addressing works. I have a variable that stores the value of 5 as follows:

```
section .data

number db 53 ; ascii code for 5

section .bss
number2 resb 1
section .text
global _start

_start:

mov eax,number
mov number2,[eax]
```

At the last two lines of the code what I am essentially trying to do is made eax act like a pointer to the data stored at number and then move this data into the number2 variable. I had though indirect register addressing was done via [register] but my code does not seem to work. Any help with regards to syntax would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Labels work as addresses in nasm so your `mov number2, [eax]` would translate to something like `mov 0x12345678, [eax]` which is of course invalid because you cannot move data to immediate operand. So you would need `mov [number2], [eax]` but that's also invalid.

You can achieve this using some register to temporarily hold the value `[eax]`:

```
mov eax, number
mov dl, [eax]
mov [number2], dl
```

Comment: AH thank you, I still don't really understand why you need that intermediate step(the dl step) and can't just take data at an address and store it directly in number ie [number2],[eax], why would we need to transfer it to another register before moving it to the variable is what confuses me. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @JmanxC Thats invalid combination of operands. There is no way to encode instruction with two memory addresses. This site shows valid combinations: [http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2010/readings/i386/MOV.htm](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2010/readings/i386/MOV.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that `number` and `number2` are not *numbers*, i.e. immediate literals. Instead they are interpreted as *absolute memory addresses* and the corresponding instructions, if they would exist would be e.g.

```
 mov eax, [0x80000100]        ;; vs
 mov [0x80000104], [eax]     ;; Invalid instruction
```

One has to pay attention to the instruction format as well, as answered by Mika Lammi -- is the instruction

```
 mov src, dst   ;; vs
 mov dst, src
```

In addition, one should match the register size to the variable size; i.e

```
.data
number   db 1;   // this is a byte
.code
mov al, number
```

Comment: AH thank you. With regards to variable size and register size i am a little confused at how data is stored in AH and AL registers. If I store the number 53 in lets say ax, would that be stored in the low order byte(ie: xxxxxxxx 53 and al) or the high order byte(Ie: 53 xxxxxxxx and ah) I was under the impression that high order means the first 8 bits in the binary number and the low order would be the last 8 bits, however I have come across forum posts that have said the opposite when it comes to these registers so I am a little confused

Comment: P.S maybe its possible that data is stored in little endian format and this is why my logic is off? Thank You for the quick response!

Comment: In IA, if AX contains the integer 53, then AH=0 and AL=53. In general, one must store the variable in `number dw 53` instead of `db 53`. _dw_ is word, _db_ is byte. To read a word from a byte sized variable is not possible, to read 32-bit word from a byte is possible through `movzx eax, byte ptr [eax]`, which fills the top 24 bits of eax with zeros, or `movsx`, which copies the sign bit of AL to the top 24 bits of eax.